# Spring Boot and WebSockets - got connection lost when sending high throuput through secured websocket using Stomp protocol

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I have 2 WebSockets endpoints:

```
registry.addEndpoint("/ws-handshake").withSockJS();
registry.addEndpoint("/api/admin/ws-handshake").withSockJS();
```

First one is without authentication, second one is secured with Spring Boot Security, uses same configuration as the HTTP security, and uses OAuth2. An authorization header is used to connect to the secure endpoint.

I use a simple for loop, as this is a POC but same amount of data will be used in production, to return a lot of records, this is done by using the SimpMessageSendingOperations class provided by Spring Boot:

```
    private SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

    @MessageMapping("/tail-topic")
    public void tailLogSendToTopic(@Payload WebSocketPoCPayload payload) throws InterruptedException {
        String topicName = "/topic/logentries";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
            WebSocketPoCMessage message = new WebSocketPoCMessage(String.format("%d : returning payload %s", i, payload.getName()));
            messageTemplate.convertAndSend(topicName, message);
            // TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
        }
        log.info("done returning all messages");
    }
```

When I send a request via the unsecured endpoint everything runs fine, I receive everything clientside.

When I send a request via the secured endpoint everything runs fine until a certain payload number (for example 1499, is always the same payload number). 
Unless I uncomment the timeout, but needs to be more than 10 milliseconds than again I get a connection lost but on later number.

Seems like my security settings disconnected the connection if they see too much traffic, am I missing something in my security configuration?

Comment: What is the object you're using for messageTemplate?
It looks like it might be something to do the the async nature of messages where by the connection is remaining open in the background after you've sent the message waiting for a reply. By adding a delay you're giving the connection enough time to keep up before reach some sort of buffer overflow and causing the connection to close.

Comment: @DanielTung It's SimpMessageSendingOperations, I will edit the question to clarify that

Comment: I really think it's to do with overloading the connection. I don't believe each send action waits for the operation to complete before moving on to the next one.

Comment: @DanielTung thank you I will have a look down that road

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there seems to be no response on this I will accept the temporary workaround as an solution:

```
private SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

@MessageMapping("/tail-topic")
public void tailLogSendToTopic(@Payload WebSocketPoCPayload payload) throws InterruptedException {
    String topicName = "/topic/logentries";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
        WebSocketPoCMessage message = new WebSocketPoCMessage(String.format("%d : returning payload %s", i, payload.getName()));
        messageTemplate.convertAndSend(topicName, message);
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
    }
    log.info("done returning all messages");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a real solution to this issue,
Although the framework is nonblocking, it still waits for a response from rabbitMQ stomp broker after each message sent.
What happens in high throughput is that sometimes the response is lost and it hangs forever waiting, in StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler, in future.get() line:

```
        try {
            ListenableFuture<Void> future = super.forward(message, accessor);
            if (message.getHeaders().get(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.IGNORE_ERROR) == null) {
                future.get();
            }
            return future;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new MessageDeliveryException(message, ex);
        }
```

The solution that worked for me is to send the messages without waiting for response, by adding a message header, like this:

```
    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor accessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
    accessor.setHeader(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.IGNORE_ERROR, true);
    accessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, message, accessor.getMessageHeaders());
```

of course in this case some of the messages may be lost in the way, but for my use case it's good enough.

another solution that worked is to wrap the convertAndSend line with a timeout and single thread executor, and then retry

Cheers

Comment: Is indeed a possible solution if you can spare to miss some messages